# usage of secondary to

Tags: sentence-construction

"A patient who presented with some infection secondary to procedures done to facilitate to drain CSF." what is the verb in the sentence?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you add more detail and maybe give some examples?

Comment: Hi, I am asking what is the verb in the sentence. the sentence given above is a complete sentence, but does it makes sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make clarifications (not the comments). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: The sentence above is **not** a complete sentence, which makes asking for the verb not useful. Again: context please.

Comment: There is no sentence verb. And it's *not* a complete sentence. All you have is a noun phrase. You haven't said what the patient did. If you want to make it a complete sentence, remove *who*; in that case, *presented* would be the verb of the sentence. I also have no idea what your question title about *to* has to do with the body of the question itself.